# depends most on how we cooperate

Tags: adverbs, superlatives

a. Whether we will succeed or not **depends most** on how we cooperate.

b. Whether we will succeed or not **depends the most** on how we cooperate.

c. Whether we will succeed or not **most depends** on how we cooperate.

d. Whether we will succeed or not **the most depends** on how we cooperate.

Do all of the above sentences mean the same?

I am not sure (c) and (d) are grammatical, although they are understandable.

I know that 'most' can sometimes mean 'extremely', but I think in these cases it is just a marker for the superlative.

Comment: Only d. is bad. The rest are correct and natural. You're right about "most" being a superlative marker here. To me, a Canadian, c. is either more formal or more British.

Comment: @gotube, agreed, except for a. and c. I would find it more natural to have "mostly" than "most".